# Creating .vtk Vector Data from .vtk scalar data

Tags: vector, visualization, vtk, scalar, paraview

I'm using a fluid simulation software which can create `.vtk` files of scalars x-velocity, y-velocity, and z-velocity. I'm trying to view streamlines using ParaView, however that requires  vectorized data. Is there an easy way to combine the scalar `.vtk` files to produce a vectorized `.vtk` file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *calculator* filter in ParaView to combine the components to a vector.
The required entities are *iHat*, *jHat*, and *kHat*, i.e. the vector constants representing unit vectors in the X, Y, and Z directions, respectively.
In your case the required line would look something like `iHat*Xvel+jHat*Yvel+kHat*Zvel` with
Xvel, Yvel and Zvel are the x, y, and z velocity components.
You can find your scalar data in the dropdown list 'Scalars'.

As an example, the following shows an example combining the coordinates (scalars) to a coordinate vector.
[image]